# python set specific locale for date as a string

Tags: python, django, date, localization, django-templates

I am using python 3.4 & django 1.10.

I have some code that sets and then dynamically displays strings to the user depending on the language they select on the template, via a select list of languages.

For example, if user selects `de`, the German values are displayed, `en` displays English (US) details, etc.

I am trying to localise the today's date string to different language codes.

I have searched google and SO, but cannot figure this out, or even if this is possible.

Does any one have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import date as _date
from datetime import datetime

GENERIC_DETAILS_LIVE_PREVIEW_LABELS = {
    'ar': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"موظف السنة",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': _date(datetime.now(), "N j, Y"),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'en': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Employee of the year",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': _date(datetime.now(), "N j, Y"),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'it': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Impiegato dell'anno",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': _date(datetime.now(), "N j, Y"),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'de': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Mitarbeiter des Jahres",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': _date(datetime.now(), "N j, Y"),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'fr': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Employé de l'année",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': _date(datetime.now(), "N j, Y"),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'es': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Empleado del año",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': _date(datetime.now(), "N j, Y"),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work using [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/).

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time
from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time

GENERIC_DETAILS_LIVE_PREVIEW_LABELS = {
    'ar': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"موظف السنة",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': format_date(datetime.now(), format='long', locale='ar'),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'en': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Employee of the year",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': format_date(datetime.now(), format='long', locale='en_US'),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'it': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Impiegato dell'anno",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': format_date(datetime.now(), format='long', locale='it_IT'),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'de': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Mitarbeiter des Jahres",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': format_date(datetime.now(), format='long', locale='de_DE'),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'fr': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Employé de l'année",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': format_date(datetime.now(), format='long', locale='fr_FR'),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
    'es': {
        ....
        'nac_generic_descriptor': u"Empleado del año",  # Employee of the year
        'nac_generic_preview_date': format_date(datetime.now(), format='long', locale='es_ES'),  # todays date localised
        ....
    },
}
```

In my template the dates are now displayed as:

en: April 3, 2017

fr: 3 avril 2017

es: 3 de abril de 2017

etcetra, etcetra.

I hope this helps someone.